# Roman-style date formatting

Tags: code-golf, date, roman-numerals

Today (March 15) is the [Ides of March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ides_of_March), best known for being the date that Julius Caesar was assassinated.

What's “Ides”?  Well, the ancient Romans didn't simply number the days of month from 1 to 31 like we do.  Instead, they had a more complex system of counting backwards to the [Kalends, Nones, or Ides](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=calhistory/earlier/roman/kalends).

### Challenge

Write, in as few bytes as possible, a program that will display the current date (on the Gregorian calendar, in the local timezone) using the abbreviated Roman-style convention described below.  Your program should work until at least the end of 2037.

### Roman dates

#### Months of the year

These should look familiar to you: Ianuarius, Februarius, Martius, Aprilis, Maius, Iunius, Iulius (Quintilis), Augustus (Sextilis), September, October, November, December.

Your program is to abbreviate all months to three letters, using the classical Latin alphabet (all caps, with J=I and U=V).  That is, `IAN`, `FEB`, `MAR`, `APR`, `MAI`, `IVN`, `IVL`, `AVG`, `SEP`, `OCT`, `NOV`, `DEC`.

#### Special dates of the month

- **Kalendis**, or the **Kalends** (abbr. `KAL`) is the first day of each month.
- **Idibus**, or the **Ides** (abbr. `ID`) is the **15th** day of March, May, July, or October; but the **13th** day of the other eight months.
- **Nonas**, or the **Nones** (abbr. `NON`) is 8 days before the Ides (5th or 7th of the month)

#### Other days of the month

Other days of the month are numbered by counting **backwards** and **inclusively** to the next reference date (Kalends, Ides, or Nones).  Notation is `AD` (abbreviation for **ante diem**, no relation to [Jesus of Nazareth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini)) followed by the appropriate **Roman numeral**.

**Exception**: Write `PR` (for **pridie**) instead of `AD II` for the day before Kalends, Nones, or Ides.

#### The leap day

In leap years, [*two* days](https://maas.museum/observations/2008/02/28/leap-day-makes-it-a-bisextile-year/) (February 24 and 25 in modern reckoning) are given the date `AD VI KAL MAR`.  (You do not need to distinguish the two days in your program.)  February 14-23 are `AD XVI KAL MAR` through `AD VII KAL MAR` as in non-leap years.  Feb 26 = `AD V KAL MAR`, Feb 27 = `AD IV KAL MAR`, Feb 28 = `AD III KAL MAR`, and Feb 29 = `PR KAL MAR`, offset by one from the corresponding dates in non-leap years.

### Example

In March, the output of your program should be:

- On March 1: `KAL MAR`
- On March 2: `AD VI NON MAR`
- On March 3: `AD V NON MAR`
- On March 4: `AD IV NON MAR`
- On March 5: `AD III NON MAR`
- On March 6: `PR NON MAR`
- On March 7: `NON MAR`
- On March 8: `AD VIII ID MAR`
- ...
- On March 13: `AD III ID MAR`
- On March 14: `PR ID MAR`
- On March 15: `ID MAR`
- On March 16: `AD XVII KAL APR`
- ...
- On March 30: `AD III KAL APR`
- On March 31: `PR KAL APR`

Answer (score 6):

## Tcl/Tk, 675 bytes

Well, I suppose I could crunch it more, but this is it for now...

```
set a {y m d}
rename proc p
p r {n {s ""}} {foreach {v d} {10 X 5 V 1 I} {while {$n>=$v} {set s $s$d;incr n -$v}};string map {VIIII IX IIII IV} $s}
p y y {expr !($y%100?$y%4:$y%400)}
p i $a {expr {($m in {3 5 7 10})?15:13}}
p n $a {expr [i $y $m $d]-8}
p k $a {expr $m==2?29+($d>24&&[y $y]):$m<8?31+$m%2:32-$m%2}
p N {} {clock f [clock se] -f {%Y %N %e}}
p M m {lindex {IAN FEB MAR APR MAI IVN IVL AVG SEP OCT NOV DEC IAN} $m-1}
p d $a {foreach f {n i k} n {NON ID KAL} mo {0 0 1} {if {$d<=[$f $y $m $d]} break}
string map {{AD I } {} {AD II } {PR }} "AD [r [expr [$f $y $m $d]+1-$d]] $n [M [expr $m+$mo]]"}
p p $a {if {$d==1} {puts "KAL [M $m]"} {puts [d $y $m $d]}}
p {*}[N]
```

**How it works**

The first thing is to collect today's date as a list: year, month, day. Everything works over that. The first of the month is a simple special case; we handle that separately.

All remaining cases work like this:

1. Find the future reference day's date in (5,7,13,15,days-in-month)
2. Get the abbreviation corresponding to that reference (`NON`, `ID`, `KAL`)
3. For Kalends we increment the month by one
4. Assemble the date string as:
   "AD <days-in-roman-numerals> <abbreviated-reference-day> <abbreviated-month-name>"
5. Apply a text replace to correct `AD I` and `AD II`.

The first step is done with a function lookup table for each of the Nones, Ides, and Kalends. Nones and Ides are straight-forward subtraction and lookup, respectively. Computing the **Kalends** is only a little more complicated (notice the trick with leap-February's day number.):

- February → 28 days + (it's a leap year AND day > 24)
- January..July → 30 days + (it's January, March, May or July)
- August..December → 31 days - (it's September or November)

The days is a simple difference: (reference_day - todays_day + 1)

Computing the **leap year** is done with a somewhat unusual arrangement of the standard formula so that it could be crunched better (removing braces and parentheses from the `expr` command).

Converting decimal to **Roman numerals** is a simple table-driven approach, stripped to use only ones, fives, and tens since we don't need to print the year in Roman numerals (domain is [1,39]).

Almost everything else is application of lookup tables.

**A note on Tcl and reducing bytes**

The first two lines of the script eat bytes by simply being shorter than spelling out `proc f {y m d}` for all instances.

Single-letter proc names and variables, of course:

```
    r := decimal→roman(n)    i := ides(y,m,d)        M := month-abbreviation(month)
    y := is-leap(year)       n := nones(y,m,d)       d := date→roman(y,m,d) [d ≠ 1]
    N := today → (y,m,d)     k := kalends(y,m,d)     p := date→roman(y,m,d) [∀d]
```

**Testing for dates other than today**

Change the very last line from `p {*}[N]` to

```
p {*}$argv
```

and run the program with the date desired:

```
% tclsh roman.tcl 2016 2 25
AD VI KAL MAR
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

(I will not give myself the checkmark, even though I have the shortest submission so far.)

## Python 3: 390 bytes

```
import time
y,m,d=time.localtime()[:3]
d-=(y%4==0)*(m==2)*(d>24)
i=13+2*(m in (3,5,7,10))
n=i-8
k=29+(0,3,0,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3)[m]
a,R={1:(0,'KAL'),d>1:(n-d,'NON'),d>n:(i-d,'ID'),d>i:(k-d,'KAL')}[1]
a+=1
A={1:'',2:'PR '}.get(a,'AD '+a//10*'X'+('','I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX')[a%10]+' ')
if d>i:m=m%12+1
M='IFMAMIIASONDAEAPAVVVECOENBRRINLGPTVC'[m-1::12]
print(A+R+' '+M)
```

## Explanation

```
y,m,d=time.localtime()[:3]
```

Gets the current date: `y`=year, `m`=month, and `d`=day.

To test the program with dates other than the current date, simply replace this line with something else.

```
d-=(y%4==0)*(m==2)*(d>24)
```

If this is February 25-29 of a leap year, subtract 1 from the date.  From this point on, we can treat February as if it's a non-leap year.

Note that, because the challenge rules don't require correct behavior in the year 2100, I used the simple 4-year Julian leap-year rule instead of the Gregorian 400-year cycle.

```
i=13+2*(m in (3,5,7,10))
```

Ides of the current month.

```
n=i-8
```

Nones of the current month.

```
k=29+(0,3,0,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3)[m]
```

One more than the number of days in the current month, equivalent to the Kalends of the *next* month.

```
a,R={1:(0,'KAL'),d>1:(n-d,'NON'),d>n:(i-d,'ID'),d>i:(k-d,'KAL')}[1]
```

`a` is the number of days until the next reference date and `R` is its abbreviation.  This expression takes advantage of the fact that if the same key is specified multiple times in the same `dict` literal, only the last one counts.

```
a+=1
```

Adjustment for inclusive counting.

```
A={1:'',2:'PR '}.get(a,'AD '+a//10*'X'+('','I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX')[a%10]+' ')
```

Stringify the count `a` to the next reference date.

- If 1, use no prefix
- If 2, use the prefix `PR`
- If 3 or higher, use the prefix `AD` + Roman numeral + space

There's probably a shorter way to do the Roman numerals, but I'm too lazy to find it.

```
if d>i:m=m%12+1
```

If after the Ides, increment the month for display.

```
M='IFMAMIIASONDAEAPAVVVECOENBRRINLGPTVC'[m-1::12]
```

Get the month name.

```
print(A+R+' '+M)
```

Finally, print the date.